# How to draw a disk with a number/string inside?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I would like to draw something like this: [image]

So far I know how to draw a disk, I use this method:

```
func drawDisk(color: UIColor, rectForDisk: CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), withStroke: Bool) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rectForDisk.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectForDisk)

    let rectForCircle = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, rectForDisk.size.width - 1, rectForDisk.size.height - 1)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, withStroke ? 1.0 : 0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
        UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectForCircle)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

What I don't know to do is to add some text in my drawing. I'm not even sure it's possible. I thought about adding a label on top of it but I was wondering if there was a better/proper way.

Comment: Look at the `UIStringDrawing` category of `NSString` in the documentation.

Comment: I'll use a label for this time but thanks for the information, I'll use that for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do what you're after is to use a label, on its own, and to set the corner radius of its layer and set the background colour. Also set the layer to clip. If you choose the corner radius correctly you can have a circular label and it will grow to an oblong bubble if required by the text it contains.